# Rotational Blur

Tags: image-processing, image-rotation, drone.io

From a drone images dataset, I would like to detect rotational motion blur. My purpose is not to correct it but rather apply a threshold to remove the worst images.
What is the easiest solution to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the blurry images of my sets are most of the time created when the drone is turning and changing direction. So I made a script (see github link below) to detect those changes and flagged the data. My program also draw an HTML map with the images in red for the potential blurry images.
[image]

https://github.com/IPGP/UAV_images_blur_detection